# Html paragraph how to align text at the center and start all the text lines at the same place or position?

Tags: css, html

```html
 <p style="text-align: center;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br> 
when an unknown printer took a galley <br>
It has survived not only five centuries,<br>
remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br>
of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.</p>
```

I was trying to write a paragraph in HTML,i need to align text at the center,the text is aligned but the problem is the text is not starting at same place or position. 
Please check the picture to understand me clearly, 
Thank You.

my Html

check this picture
[image: The image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only able to style the `<p>` element, then do the following:

Add `display: flex` to convert the `p` into a flex container, and `text-align: left` to keep the text justified on the left.

Set the direction of the container to `column` so that it will keep the breaks, and then `align-items: center`.

`align-items` will align the elements on the cross-axis, which in this case is the horizontal axis.

```html
 <p style="text-align: left; display:flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br> 
when an unknown printer took a galley <br>
It has survived not only five centuries,<br>
remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br>
of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you this is the best because i have complex page and its hard for to change all the P tags into div,

Comment: Just keep in mind that in many cases, such as this one, there is more than one way to approach it.

Comment: @JimaleAbdi You don't need to change the `p` into a `div`. This may work, but Itay Gal's answer below is the simplest and most straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest way and it's simple. You set a fixed width and giving it auto margin so it will be centered.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br> when an unknown printer took a galley <br> It has survived not only five centuries,<br> remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br> of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.</p>
</div>
```

If you layout is more complex you might want to use flex. For example:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content{
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br> when an unknown printer took a galley <br> It has survived not only five centuries,<br> remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br> of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the paragraph inside a div (with a fixed width) and center the div on the page then you can use text-align to style the paragraph itself (inside the div). I think you want `text-align: left;` for the paragraph text itself.
Here is the CSS for the div wrapper.

## CSS

```
.text-wrapper{
width: 300px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

## HTML

```
   <body>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <p style="text-align: left;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br>
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br> 
        when an unknown printer took a galley <br>
        It has survived not only five centuries,<br>
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br>
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.</p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br>
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br>
        when an unknown printer took a galley <br>
        It has survived not only five centuries,<br>
        remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br>
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```html
 <div style="margin:0 auto;width:50vw"><p style="text-align: left;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<br>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <br> 
when an unknown printer took a galley <br>
It has survived not only five centuries,<br>
remaining essentially unchanged. It was<br>
of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum<br>
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker.</p></div>
```

`text-align: center-right` is not a valid attribute. We can however wrap a div around your paragraph and move that into the center of the page with margin:0 auto. We also have to give this div a fixed width.

Comment: Thank You, it works but if i resize the browser also the text is resized and that is another problem because i'm used mobiles

Comment: yes, that is due to the "width:50vw". You are actually better off using Itay's more complex solution, but change the .content style to use flex-shrink: 1; (instead of flex-shrink:0)

Comment: @wlh solution is the best way,Thank you again for your effort

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change 'center' with 'left'. it will fix it.

```css
.container {
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<p class='container'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan.
</p>
```